# Google Chrome attempts to connect to Google domains with non-Google IP addresses

Tags: networking, google-chrome, router, dns

I currently have Little Snitch 3.6.1 installed on a Macbook running El Capitan. My primary browser is Google Chrome.

When I'm just doing normal internet browsing, I'll get connection alerts that Chrome wants to connect to Google domains (both TCP and UDP connections, on both ports 80 and 443), even if I'm not explicitly using anything related to the domain at the time I get an alert.

I know when Chrome needs to connect to an actual Google domain as the IP address points to Google and it has a reverse DNS name.

[image]

I don't have a screenshot, but for example, yesterday I got a alert that Chrome wanted to connect to www.google.com on port 80. There was no reverse DNS name, and the IP address was associated with my ISP (when looking up the IP address one of the details was "imported inetnum object for OCPL"). However, under the network settings on my Macbook I've inputted OpenDNS addresses).

Does anyone know why Chrome would attempt to connect to these Google domains that have IP addresses associated with my ISP even though I'm not currently googling anything etc? I've tried calling my ISP's technical support but they don't offer much help.

It also happens when I google things using Safari as well. Second screenshot shows Little Snitch screenshot and third is an IP lookup of the first IP address associated with the connection attempt.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your ISP could be caching requests ... or using some kind of proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolving www.google.com will get you to a close mirror, and if your ISP is hosting some, then the IP(s) you get will usually be inside their network.  Google buys "space" all over the world to have fast-responding front-end servers close to customers and uses DNS to send you to the closest one.  If you are using Google's DNS as well (8.8.8.8), then you get the absolute closest mirror of www.google.com to you (because they get your specific source IP making the query).  And by closest, I mean fastest responding.

E.g., www.google.com for me resolves to an IP address that is four router hops away from me within my ISPs netblock (just like you), and on average, 16ms round-trip time.  That's pretty "close".

Welcome to the "cloud".